# Save timer time and resume on onResume

Tags: java, android, timer

I'am a beginner.

I have a timer in my puzzle game. But there is a bug. When the user turns off the screen, the timer doesn`t stop. If user turns screen on again he can see game over screen and this is not good from UX perspective.

Here is my code for timer

```
private void initializeProgressBar() {
    //initialize progressbar 

    progress = ApplicationConstants.GAME_TIME;

    mProgress = (ProgressBarDetermininate) findViewById(R.id.progressDeterminate);
    mProgress.setMax(progress);
    mProgress.setProgress(progress );
    timer = new Timer();
    progressBarUpdateTask = new ProgressBarUpdateTask();
    timer.schedule(progressBarUpdateTask, 20, 20);

}

class ProgressBarUpdateTask extends TimerTask {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress-=1;
            if(progress==0)
            {
                TimeOver();
            }
            mProgress.setProgress(progress);
        }

        });
      }

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.timer.cancel();

}
```

I can`t figure out how to fix this onResume, because now timer stops when user turn off the screen, but doesnt resume when user turn on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into CountDownTimer. The timer you are using now is not supposed to really be used like that. Unfortunately there is no pause so onTick save a variable to know what the timer is currently at, then on pause cancel the timer. then in onresume create a new time and set the time to the variable you are using to keep track of the last timer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Thanks! I hope I will know how to convert my timer to CountDownTimer :)

Answer (score 1):

Then you should pause the timer in your `onPause()` method not cancel it and in the `onResume()` method you could restart the timer with the seconds which were left, before the screen has been turned off. For further informations about the lifecycle of an activity have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

But what I think you really need is the CountDownTimer class not the Timer class.

Comment: Hmmm...but how to pause timer? I was looking for informations on google, but nothing usable for beginners :(

Comment: unfortunatly there is no way to pause a timer only cancel it. you need to create variable of the current time when it is paused and recreate the timer in onResume

Comment: like @tomer shemesh said, save the left time in a variable and then start a new timer with the left time